# Listening to notifications with chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, notifications, listener

I am looking for a solution to listen notifications with my chrome extension.

But chrome.notifications only allows me to send notifications but not listening to notifications.

So is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly does "to listen notifications" mean?

Comment: I want to trigger some code when there's a notification

Comment: There's no such event but you can detect notifications from web pages by overriding `Notification` constructor in [page context](/a/9517879).